# gunicorn not accepting arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I am setting up a Flask app on a Google VM. I have previously done something very similar on the same VM, but for whatever reason after creating a new virtual environment things aren't working.

```
cd /home/joshuasmith6556/joshthings-server

sudo /home/joshuasmith6556/joshthings-server/env/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --certfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.joshthings.com/fullchain.pem --keyfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.joshthings.com/privkey.pem --workers=6 app:app
```

When I run the above script to launch my server on HTTPS using some cert files I have generated, gunicorn throws an error: `Error: No such option: --bind`. If I put app:app before the other flags, it says `Error: Got unexpected extra argument (app:app)`. If I put --certfile first, I get `Error: No such option: --certfile`. Essentially, gunicorn always complains about the first argument I give it and never launches the server. Any ideas about what is wrong or what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here the main source of error might be a typo with "bind" missing an "=" sign after it. It should be something like:

```
sudo /home/joshuasmith6556/joshthings-server/env/bin/gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:443 --certfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.joshthings.com/fullchain.pem --keyfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.joshthings.com/privkey.pem --workers=6 app:app
```

The WSGI_APP flag is [expected](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn) to be in the end, so there is no conflict with this. I think when you have put certfile into first place, you could also not put the equals sign, and that's why it gave you an error.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I checked bash history and had the equal sign with certfile all along, and after adding an equal sign to bind I still get the exact same error. It's good to know that WSGI_APP should be at the end